# Pyodbc bulk insert statement won't parameterise

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc

I'm trying to get Python to populate SQL tables by cleaning csv files, and then doing a bulk upload in SQL. When I try to perform the insert in the following manner:

```
sqlCommand = "BULK INSERT ? FROM ? WITH ( BATCHSIZE = 1000, ROWTERMINATOR = '\\n', KEEPNULL )"
cursor.execute(sqlCommand,tableName,fileName)
```

I get the following error: Incorrect syntax near '@P1'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW);

However, if I do it this way:

```
"BULK INSERT {0} FROM {1} WITH ( BATCHSIZE = 1000, ROWTERMINATOR = '\\n', KEEPNULLS )".format(tableName,fileName)
cursor.execute(sqlCommand)
```

It works perfectly.

Is there a nicer way to get this to work?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise that you couldn't parameterise table names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `?` [parameter](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/GettingStarted#Parameters) placeholder is not allowed for table names (and column) names in T-SQL.

The second option is using string formatting in Python to build the T-SQL statement before execution against the database server. This is also known as [dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html), and is the only way to accomplish your task using `BULK INSERT`.

Dynamic SQL (and unvalidated input in general) introduces [SQL injection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx) vulnerability, so make sure you are validating the `tableName` and `fileName` variables if this is a user-facing script.